# Split string with string and retrieve value c#

Tags: c#, string

I have below string

```
string arguments = "-p=C:\Users\mplususer\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\o9\o9\bin\Debug\o9.exe""-t=False""-r=TestRun";
```

I want to split string with `"-t="` and get `false` value

```
if (arguments.Contains("-t="))
{
    string[] value = arguments.Split(new string[] { "\"-t=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (value.Length != 0)
    {
        mode = value[1].Replace("\"", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: `String.Split` never returns an empty `string[]`. If the delimiter is not contained you get an array with one string which is the complete source string. So your `value.Length != 0`-check is incorrect. It's redundant anyway because you have used already `if (arguments.Contains("-t="))`.

Comment: Your code for setting arguments wouldnt compile .. so maybe something else is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make an `IndexOf`:

```
var i = myString.IndexOf("-t=") + 3;
if(i != -1)
    value = myString.SubString(i, myString.IndexOf("\"", i) - i);
```

You can also use a regex for this:

```
var r = new Regex("-t (true|false)");
var g = r.Match(myString).Groups;
if(g.Count > 1)
    value = Convert.ToBoolean(g[1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also like this like your approach without regex:

```
string arguments = "-p=C:\\Users\\mplususer\\Documents\\SharpDevelop Projects\\o9\\o9\\bin\\Debug\\o9.exe\" \"-t=False\" \"-r=TestRun";

if (arguments.Contains("-t="))
{
    string splitted = arguments.Split(new string[] { "\"-t=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
    string value = splitted.Split(new string[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you split on "-t", you get two fragments. The fragment after that delimiter also contains a "-r" option - which is the issue you are probably seeing.

If you *know* that the "-t" option is always followed by a "-r", you could simply split on `new string[] { "\"-t=", "\"-r=" }`. Then you get three fragments and you still want the second one (at index 1).